# Calculating the integral $\int_{C(0,3/4)}\frac{\operatorname{Log}(1+z)}{(z-1/2)^3}dz$ using residues theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration, residue-calculus

I’m trying to calculate the integral $\int_{C(0,3/4)}\frac{\operatorname{Log}(1+z)}{(z-1/2)^3}dz$. Can I use the residues theorem here? I’m thinking the value of the integral would be given by $2\pi i {\rm Res}(f(z),1/2)$, where $1/2$ is a pole of order $3$ and $f(z)=\frac{\operatorname{Log}(1+z)}{(z-1/2)^3}$, is that correct?

P.S.: By $\operatorname{Log}(z)$ I mean the function $z \rightarrow \log|z|+i\operatorname{Arg}(z)$, where $\operatorname{Arg}(z)$ is the only argument of $z$ belonging to the interval $]-\pi,\pi[$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\log_0$ ?

Comment: @K.defaoite I added that to the question.

Comment: This is usually written using a capital "L" as $\operatorname{Log}$, and the corresponding "arg" is usually written as $\operatorname{Arg}$.

Comment: @K.defaoite Sorry. I corrected the question.

Comment: Yes, your approach is correct. All you have to do is compute the residue at the pole of order $3$ and you are done.